# I would like to perform multiple actions in one Excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

I would like to perform multiple actions in one formula.

First I would like to replace the content of cells in a specific column. Every cell in this column with a 'space' should be emptied.

Second I would like to select the corresponding rows with these empty cells.

Third I would like to remove these rows.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you sure you want formula and not a macro?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the macro recorder for this. You can activate this option by first going to the Excel Menu (office button) and then Options -> General tab -> Tick "Developper tab".

On the developer tab click record macro and give it an appropriate name. Select the entire column, Ctrl+H and replace " " (without quotes) with "" (without quotes). Hit F5 -> Special -> Blanks and then Ctrl+- -> Delete rows. Now you can go to the developer tab and press stop.

You can now use this macro in the future.